# jquery set div attr id not working but for the rest of the elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a clone of a div along with all the elements it contains. For the new div I'm changing the IDs, I'm able to change all of them but the div one, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/search" method="post">             
    <div class="card" id="criteriaContainer_0">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12" id="andOr_0">And</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="leftParenthesis_0" readonly>
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="addLeftParenthesis_0" title="Add left parenthesis" onclick="addLeftParenthesis(this)" type="button">+</button> 
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" id="delLeftParenthesis_0" title="Remove left parenthesis" onclick="delLeftParenthesis(this)" type="button">-</button> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="criteria_0" placeholder="Enter search term" name="criteria_0" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">                                  
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" id="delRightParenthesis_0" title="Remove right parenthesis" onclick="delRightParenthesis(this)" type="button">-</button> 
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="addRightParenthesis_0" title="Add right parenthesis" onclick="addRightParenthesis(this)" type="button">+</button> 
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rightParenthesis_0" readonly>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                  
    </div>              

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 offset-sm-10">
            <button class="btn" id="addCriteria" title="Add (Up to 5 criteria)" onclick="addSearchTerm()" type="button"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle" style="font-size:48px;color:green"></i></button>
            <button class="btn" id="delCriteria" title="Delete search term" onclick="delSearchTerm()" type="button"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle" style="font-size:48px;color:red"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>          
</form>
```

**JQuery**

```
var current_id = 0;
function addSearchTerm() {
    current_id++;
    var newCriteria = $("#criteriaContainer_0").clone(true);

    // Setting Ids for new elements
    // NOT WORKING (Always shows as criteriaContainer_0 in the new ones)
    $(newCriteria).find("#criteriaContainer_0").attr("id", "criteriaContainer_" + current_id);

    // Beyond this point everything works as expected (andOr_1, andOr_2, ...)
    $(newCriteria).find("#andOr_0").attr("id", "andOr_" + current_id);
    $(newCriteria).find("#leftParenthesis_0").attr("id", "leftParenthesis_" + current_id);
    $(newCriteria).find("#addLeftParenthesis_0").attr("id", "addLeftParenthesis_" + current_id);
    $(newCriteria).find("#delLeftParenthesis_0").attr("id", "delLeftParenthesis_" + current_id);
    $(newCriteria).find("#criteria_0").attr("id", "criteria_" + current_id);
    $(newCriteria).find("#delRightParenthesis_0").attr("id", "delRightParenthesis_" + current_id);
    $(newCriteria).find("#addRightParenthesis_0").attr("id", "addRightParenthesis_" + current_id);
    $(newCriteria).find("#rightParenthesis_0").attr("id", "rightParenthesis_" + current_id);

    // Cleaning values
    $(newCriteria).find("#leftParenthesis_" + current_id).val("");
    $(newCriteria).find("#criteria_" + current_id).val("");
    $(newCriteria).find("#rightParenthesis_" + current_id).val("");

    // Insert new criteria
    $(newCriteria).insertAfter(".card:last");

    if (current_id > 4) {
        $("#addCriteria").prop("disabled",true);
    } else {
        $("#addCriteria").prop("disabled",false);
    }               
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to change

```
var newCriteria = $("#criteriaContainer_0").clone(true);
```

to

```
  var newCriteria = $("#criteriaContainer_0").clone(true).attr("id", "criteriaContainer_" + current_id);
```

Comment: That worked! Can you please give an explanation why there and not in a separate line as I had it?

Comment: That's because after the clone you have two divs with the same id.

Comment: Makes perfectly sense!